# TypeORM "find" only returning one result even with multiple results in the table

Tags: typeorm

I have schema of

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({ name: 'monthly_invoice_rollup' })
export class MonthlyInvoiceRollup {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    Invoiceno: string;

    @Column()
    ClientID: string;

    @Column()
    Rollup_code: string;

    @Column()
    Rollup_desc: string;
}
```

I have a class where I set it like

```js
this.monthlyInvoiceRollup = getRepository(MonthlyInvoiceRollup)
```

and I call it like

```js
const results = await this.monthlyInvoiceRollup.find({
    where: { "Invoiceno": "134" },
});
```

but it only returns the first result in the table even though I know I have multiple results

[image]

Comment: The design is not correct. By [definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/ddl-constraints.html): *primary key constraint is simply a combination of a unique constraint and a not-null constraint.* You can't have multiple entry in the same table with the same primary key. You must find another way to identify multiple entries given a common value. That is why TypeORM returns only one entry: given the primary key there can be only one or zero entry in the DB.

Comment: PS: I don't know what DB you are using but (given the TypeORM schema) enabling ```synchronize: true``` should fail because multiple entries have the same primary key value.

Comment: @CarloCorradini you're correct. If you want to submit an answer I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design is not correct. By [definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/ddl-constraints.html): primary key constraint is simply a combination of a unique constraint and a not-null constraint. You can't have multiple entry in the same table with the same primary key. You must find another way to identify multiple entries given a common value. That is why TypeORM returns only one entry: given the primary key there can be only one or zero entry in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

as it is said above the primary key is a combination of unique and not null constraints, in your given example your primary key is invoiceno, foreign key is clientID so your relation is that the client can have 1 or n invoices, invoice related to 1.1 client.
so lets say that ClientID = 134 that can be repeated because it is simply foreign key, so you can lookup your invoices based on the clientID